# member-to-pointer variable only accepted as function template argument in Clang with -std=c++17

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, language-lawyer

https://godbolt.org/z/o7rBT9

This compiles fine in on Clang with `-std=c++14`

```
struct Vecs
{
    enum class VecIndex { first, second };
    std::vector<int> vec1, vec2;

    template <VecIndex> struct vecForIndex;
    template <> struct vecForIndex<VecIndex::first> {
        static constexpr auto vecPtr = &Vecs::vec1;
    };
    template <> struct vecForIndex<VecIndex::second> {
        static constexpr auto vecPtr = &Vecs::vec2;
    };

    template <std::vector<int> Vecs::*vecPtr>
    static void work() {}

    static void workSpecificVec()  { 
        work<&Vecs::vec1>(); 
    }
};
```

But this version of workSpecificVec doesn't:

```
static void workSpecificVec()  { 
    work<vecForIndex<VecIndex::first>::vecPtr>(); 
}
```

The latter does compile with `-std=c++17`.

Why?

P.S. Neither gcc nor msvc compile the above with any standard. IIUC explicit specializations in class scope [have been allowed since c++14](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue727), so it seems like an issue either with the compilers or with my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit specializations in class scope are a C++17 feature ([CWG 727](https://wg21.link/cwg727) was not a DR against C++14, it was new for C++17) that gcc just doesn't implement yet (this is [gcc bug 85282](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282)).

There's another C++17 feature at play here - which is the widening of what kinds of arguments can be used as non-type template parameters ([N4198](https://wg21.link/n4198) for explanation, [N4268](https://wg21.link/n4268) for wording). In C++14, `vecForIndex<VecIndex::first>::vecPtr` wasn't an allowable non-type template argument because the *only* allowable arguments for pointers to members (as in your example) were:

- Precisely expressions of the form `&T::X` (like, literally that syntax)
- An arbitrary constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value.

And that's it. `vecForIndex<VecIndex::first>::vecPtr` is neither of those things, so it's ill-formed in C++14. In C++17, the restrictions on non-type template parameters are much much looser, so this just works.

---

If you want all of this to stay within the class body, you can use a function template with `if constexpr` instead of a specialized class template. It's less code too:

```
template <VecIndex I>
constexpr auto vecForIndex()
{
    if constexpr (I == VecIndex::first) return &Vecs::vec1;
    else if constexpr (I == VecIndex::second) return &Vecs::vec2;
}
```

and then:

```
static void workSpecificVec()  { 
    work<vecForIndex<VecIndex::first>()>(); 
}
```